# Need a regular expression which accepts 4 numbers and 1 character exactly in the same format

Tags: regex

I need a regular expression which accepts following format
`1111A` or `1234B`.

I used `/([0-9]{0,4})&([A-Z])/` but not able to get it.

Comment: Remove `&` and probably enclose with `^` and `$`. `^[0-9]{0,4}[A-Z]$` might suffice. Please add some valid/invalid input.

Comment: it is accepting AAAAA also. I need 4 numerics and 1 alpha

Comment: No, `^[0-9]{0,4}[A-Z]$` does not. 4 or 0-4? If only 4, use `^[0-9]{4}[A-Z]$`

Comment: I need exactly in this format 1111A, 1234B or 5555C

Comment: `^[0-9]{4}[A-Z]$` should work in JS, ``^[0-9]{4}[A-Z]\Z`` for Python, ``^[0-9]{4}[A-Z]\z`` for PCRE/.NET/Java

Comment: @wiktor-stribiżew thank you it resolved my issue

Comment: 4 any numbers or 4 sequential numbers or 4 repeated numbers?

Answer (score 0):

Try using `^\d{4}[A-Z]$`

```js
const re = RegExp(/^\d{4}[A-Z]$/);
console.log(re.test('1111A'));
console.log(re.test('1A111'));
console.log(re.test('1111AA'));
```